# Are there configuration settings to remember docked toolwindow positions in the VBE?

Tags: excel, rubberduck, vba

I've just installed the [Rubberduck add-in](http://rubberduck-vba.com).

If I configure my `vbe` windows so I can see your duck-windows it all looks lovely but when I restart Excel it is back the way it was before: is there a way around this so my configuration of the `vbe` persists?

Comment: come say hello whytheq: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking

Comment: Hey there. Devs are chatting about this now. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27373076#27373076

Comment: I've edited the title to better reflect what the question body is about. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @RubberDuck I feel honoured to have created the tag ...did I case it ok, or should it be hyphenated or with a "D"?

Comment: It's perfectly fine @whytheq. That's how it is on Code Review SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to configure this, but no, it has not been implemented yet.  Essentially, this would involve remembering whether the dockable windows are currently displayed when the add-in is unloaded.

In order to do this, Rubberduck could store these positions in the settings file and display them when it is loaded.

If you wish, you can create an issue for this, and the team may implement it in time for the next release if it has enough support.

**Full Disclosure:** I am currently working on the Rubberduck Team.

Comment: The window positions themselves should save. It's just the visibility that doesn't persist.

Comment: @RubberDuck OK, then this should be easy enough.  In fact, we used to do something similar when we would reload windows for different languages.